# Z3 fails to check reasoning in predicate logic for an example from SYMBOLIC LOGIC By Lewis Carroll

Tags: logic, z3, predicate

```
; All rabbits, that are not greedy, are black
; No old rabbits are free from greediness
; Therefore: Some black rabbits are not old
(declare-sort U) 
(declare-fun g (U) Bool)
(declare-fun b (U) Bool)
(declare-fun o (U) Bool) 
(assert (forall ((x U)) (=> (not (g x)) (b x) ))) 
(assert (forall ((x U)) (=> (o x) (g x) ))) 
(assert (not (exists ((x U)) (and (b x) (not (o x))))))
(check-sat)
; returns sat
```

I was checking tautology of conjunction of premises implication of conclusion (to assert negation) as well as contradiction of the set of premises with negation of conclusion. Say, for contradiction, I expected unsat

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the model z3 returns. You can achieve this by sticking:

```
(get-model)
```

after your `(check-sat)`. If you do that, z3 prints:

```
sat
(
  ;; universe for U:
  ;;   U!val!0
  ;; -----------
  ;; definitions for universe elements:
  (declare-fun U!val!0 () U)
  ;; cardinality constraint:
  (forall ((x U)) (= x U!val!0))
  ;; -----------
  (define-fun g ((x!0 U)) Bool
    true)
  (define-fun b ((x!0 U)) Bool
    false)
  (define-fun o ((x!0 U)) Bool
    false)
)
```

This is a bit of a mouthful. But it essentially says: (1) Imagine a world where there's exactly one rabbit. (2) All rabbits are `greedy`. (3) No rabbit is `black`. (4) No rabbit is `old`.

If you think about this, it indeed satisfies your constraints. So, what's going on here? This is typical of translating "English" to "formal"-logic. It's often the case that there are some implied constraints that go without saying in the natural language. And indeed, this is the case here too. What's implicit is that "there's some rabbit that's not greedy" which you have not captured in your formalization. If we add this:

```
(assert (exists ((x U)) (not (g x))))
```

then z3 will indeed say `unsat`; as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I started to recheck with other solvers and came to the same hypothesis in https://www.umsu.de/trees/ with ∀x(¬G(x)→B(x)),∀x(O(x)→G(x)),∃x(¬G(x))|=∃x(B(x)∧¬O(x))